# $n$-th root of meromorphic functions of several complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a "nice" meromorphic function of several complex variables on some domain $\Omega$. I wonder if the following claim is true.

**Claim**. $f$ admits a global $n$-th root over $\Omega$ if and only if the divisor of $f$ is an $n$-tuple of some divisor. Namely, there exists a meromorphic function $g:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $f=g^{n}$ if and only if there is a divisor $D$ on $\Omega$ such that $\mathrm{div}(f)=nD$.

It seems like this is true for the single complex variable case, but I am a bit unsure of what happens in the higher dimensional case.